# CMake - determine build type in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

Running `cmake` on VS 2015, we don't have access to the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`

We need to create a URL string that depends on the build type.

The following works on `qtcreator`:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

string(TOLOWER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} BUILD_TYPE_LOWER)

ExternalProject_Add(targetName
    URL https://artifactory.blabla-${BUILD_TYPE_LOWER}.zip
    ...
)
```

But I don't know how to make it work on VS.

I tried with:

```
URL if $<CONFIG:Debug> https://artifactory.blabla-debug.zip
```

But it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.